# About & Preferences flyouts are blank after converting from win8 RC to win8 RTM

Tags: javascript, windows-8, windows-runtime

Our about and preferences flyouts, which worked under RC, are now blank/white after converting the project to RTM. We had used example code from the win8 labs to construct these and they were working before. I have read the migration guide and have made changes that seemed applicable. Is anyone else experiencing this problem, and is there a solution for this? We are using Javascript. Thanks.

Comment: Is the content in the preferences? (E.g. if you use DOM Explorer, does the content show there, but it's just not visible), Or is some error happening failing to load the content?

Comment: Any chance we can see some of what you are doing in markup and code?

Comment: The preferences page contans the "remember where I am" switch. The about page contains our company name, rating, etc. and is embedded in the HTML. I do see content for the about page when I use breakpoints and use the debugger. For now I would like to try creating an entirely new project and just add those two pages and see what happens and then I will post the results. Thanks for your responses.

Comment: I created a new project with an about page, again using the win8 labs tutorial, and about shows up in the settings page, but when you tap about, the settings page goes away and you do not get the about page.

Comment: The following code is put in default.js before the if (app.sessionState.history) statement:                               app.onsettings = function (e) {
    e.detail.applicationcommands = {
        // Add an About command
        "about": {
            href: "/pages/about/about.html",
            title: "About"
        }
    }

    WinJS.UI.SettingsFlyout.populateSettings(e);
};
 An about folder is created within the pages folder. Then an about page control is created. THis code replaces div fragment in about.html:

Comment: <div id="about" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.SettingsFlyout" data-win-options="{width: 'narrow'}">
    <div class="SettingsPane">
        <div class="win-label">
            <button onclick="WinJS.UI.SettingsFlyout.show()" class="win-backbutton">
            </button>
            <span class="SettingsTitle">About</span>
        </div>
        <article class="SettingsContent">
            <h2>Content</h2>
            
        </article>
    </div>
</div>
Finally, this code is added to about.css:

Comment: .SettingsPane {
    margin-top:36px;
    margin-left:48px;
}

.SettingsTitle {
    margin-left: 36px;
}

.SettingsContent {
     margin-top: 24px;
}
That's it! You can start with a blank project. I chose a grid, and did those steps. So whether its the project we carried over from RC or a new project in RTM, you get the same result.

Comment: 09/04/2012 --  we discovered that you if you looked close, you could see the content of the these pages, but it was as if the opacity was set very low, so we tried playing with the opacity, but that had not effect. We also tried several z-index values; again, no effect. We had also tried aliceblue as a background color in the settings pane and that did not work, but when we made the background color black, the our content showed up. A number of other dark colors will work as well. So the solution is to apply a dark background color to the settings pane in the respective css files

Answer (score 0):

With the RTM release there are a lot of breaking changes, so you should take a look to the migration provided by Microsoft [migration guide](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30706)

If you have used `z-index`, you must know that z-index range changed from 1000-1003 to 1000-1008

Regards.

Comment: as I noted above, I have read the migration guide and made appropriate changes noted in the guide. we are not using z-index.